# Jmeter - passing JSON response array to the next graphql http request

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 graphql http requests as following.

The first http request's response returning json like so:

{"data":{"customers":{"customerIds":["0e1c7b05-79c6-40c6-9144-7230a836fe04", "45677b05-79tt-56c6-9144-7230a836bbbb"]}}}

I then created the json extractor and the beanshell to save the customer ids in the property

[image]

[image]

The 2nd Http request then using the above customerids property as part of the graphql request body

[image]

but I;m getting the 500 InternalServerError due to the quotes in the list customerids below not being escaped.  how can i escape them ?

```
POST data:
{"query":"query getCustomerInfo {\n  getCustomerInfo(customerIds: \"["0e1c7b05-79c6-40c6-9144-7230a836fe04"]\") {\n firstName\n lastName\n school\n }\n}"}
```

Comment: Which version of Jmeter are you using? why are you using ${__setpropety........}, use can use directly the ID of json extractor right, is there any requirement for you to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) into your scripts

   > When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.
2. [Don't use Beanshell, since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) for scripting

So replace your Beanshell Assertion with the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following code:

```
props.put("customerIds",vars.get("customerIds").replaceAll("\"","\\\\\""));
```

This way you will get the following `customerIds` property value:

```
[\"0e1c7b05-79c6-40c6-9144-7230a836fe04\",\"45677b05-79tt-56c6-9144-7230a836bbbb\"]
```